# How to make stock browser stop asking which browser I want to use?

Tags: browser, default-applications

I know almost this exact question title was asked, but the original asker stated that he had not set any browser as a default. I, on the other hand, ALWAYS select the stock web browser as the default.

Nonetheless, every time I open the browser and every time I click a link I am asked to select a default web browser. I had dolphin and opera mini installed, but deleted dolphin in hopes that would help the issue since Opera was not always showing as an option.

However, now Opera shows up every time as an alternate and the problem persists as it always has. I do not know of any catalyst that could have caused this behaviour. I updated to Gingerbread (using T-Mobile G2) some time ago (like July 2011) and this problem has only been around for maybe a month or so.

Any help with this?

*As I said, I already select that the stock browser be the default. If I check the settings, Opera mini is not set for any defaults. This is seriously irritating.*

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

1. Tap your device "home" button;
2. Tap your device "menu" button;
3. Tap "Settings";
4. Tap "Applications";
5. Tap "Manage Applications":

   Look for the browsers in question, notice "Launch by default", with the caption stating "No defaults set", make sure the button "Clear defaults" is tapped, if it's disabled, it means its the only one in use. i.e. no other alternative app that handles the browser.
   Repeat that for other browsers you may have.

Next time you launch the browser, a pop-up will appear with a choice, there's a check-box underneath, "Make default", tap that, and next time, the default browser of your choosing is used.

*This applies to other apps also that handles the flow of actions as well, such as an alternative to messaging, email, music etc.*

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, using Android version 9 (aka Pie).

Home, settings, apps, Chrome (or any browser your phone gives you the option to use when you click on a link), Browser app. A list of unselected browsers will appear and you can select which one you want to use.

The picture here shows what happened after I selected a default browser. But initially, the list of browsers will just have un-ticked circles next to them.

[image]

Here's a slightly faster way in Android 9:

Home, settings, apps, upper right 3 dots, Default apps, Browser app. A list of unselected browsers will appear and you can select which one you want to use.